# Selecting multi features on map based on Datagrid row/rows selection?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, esri-geodatabase

I was trying to select feature depending on the selection change  of the datagrid. Each row of the datagrid consists of the feature OID and feature Name etc.

While selecting I am seeing that more features are selected in the map than I selected in the row. While investigating the issue, I found that a feature OID is unique through out its own attribute Table but it may also be available in different feature Attribute Table.

Here is the code #

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.SelectedRows)
{       grdrows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dataGrid.SelectedRows[iCount].Cells[0].Value));
 iCount++;
 }
            int[] ids = grdrows.ToArray();
            map.ClearSelection();
            if (dataGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.SelectedRows)
               {
                   int objectID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                   string featureName = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                    while (counter != map.LayerCount - 1)
                     {
                       IFeatureLayer featureLayer =
                      (IFeatureLayer)map.get_Layer(counter);

                       ISelectionSet pSelSet =
                       ((IFeatureSelection)featureLayer).SelectionSet;
                       pSelSet.AddList(ids.Count(), ref ids[0]);
                      counter++;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Then I have added this if but it did not work. The problem is that post adding the if statement multiple row selection does not select multiple features. It selects only the last feature. I need help.
I have put the selection code in this .

```
if ( featureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName == featureName )
```